# Stop iFrame content loading Again

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, iframe

I created an dashboard app with anularjs and it has a iFrame which load .mrt file,
what i want is to load that .mrt file only once.

first time dashboard app click and dashboard getting loaded, then i switch to another app and when i click again dashboard it should show the first time loaded content inside iframe without loading or refreshing it again.

**Controller**

```
$scope.dashboardURL="url";
            document.getElementById('reportFram').setAttribute('src',$scope.dashboardURL);
```

**View**

```
<iframe class="layout-column flex" layout="column" flex fill-width
                frameborder='0'
                id="reportFram"
                marginwidth="0"
                marginheight="0"
                onload=""
                allowfullscreen>
        </iframe>
```

Comment: Each time you render an iframe it will make it's own request based on the `src`. You can't control that request. What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: That .mrt file i'm loading, take quite time to get loaded. so loading every time is a problem, i just need this  .mrt file to load once.
PS: this is stimulsoft report, if u guys have other ideas to load .mrt files in my angular app, i am open to listen to them too.